# Django template multidimensionnal array acces in for loop

Tags: python, arrays, django, for-loop, django-templates

I ran against an annoying problem in a Django template.
I have a 3 dimensional array and want to loop through the first dimension in my template as such :

`{% for item in array %} {{array.i.0.0}} {% endfor %}`

Now, I am aware that this would not work, since i is undefined, but I've tried using `{{forloop.counter0}}` to no avail and was looking for a similarly simple way of doing so.
I've found [this link](http://ralphminderhoud.com/posts/variable-as-dictionary-key-in-django-templates/) which uses a template filter... is it the only solution?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you are trying to do here. Can't you access it with `{{ item.0.0 }}`.

Comment: @HåkenLid it does not appear to work. Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Can you write the logic in python code, so we can understand what you are trying to do? Also, what kind of data type is your array? Is it a numpy array?

Comment: @HåkenLid It's a nested array : `array = [[['value' for i in range(x)] for j in range(y)] for k in range(z)]`

Answer (score 0):

I did try the custom template filter solution from the link in my original post but failed at first. I got a ValueError with `{{array|access:key.0.0}}` probably because the whole "key.0.0" bit was being sent to the filter. So, using the "with" template tag I was able to achieve what I wanted.

    `{% load filters %} // File containing my custom filters
    {% with array|access:forloop.counter0 as index %}
        {{index.0.0}}
    {% endwith %}`

I still don't know if there exists a simpler solution, but it works and is pretty clean as far as I'm concerned.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

First, you want to define two template filters, which for ease can live in your views.py

```
@register.filter
def index(List, i):
    return List[int(i)]

@register.filter
def entry_num_array(List):
    return range(len(List))
```

Then in your template

```
{% for inner_array1 in main_array %}
        {% for counter1 in inner_array1|entry_num_array %}
            {{inner_array1|index:counter1}}|
            {%for inner_array2 in inner_array1 %}
                {% for counter1 in inner_array1|entry_num_array %}
                    {{inner_array2|index:counter2}}|
                {% endfor %}            
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

You may have to use "with" to get it to work: